# Can't get user_left event from telegram channel

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

There is the event [`ChatAction`](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telethon.events.html?highlight=events#telethon.events.chataction.ChatAction) that allows you to handle events from chat such as user joined, left, or new pin. 
But when a chat has a lot of users I can't get `user_left` event, only `user_join`.

How can I handle this event without counting of users?

```
@client.on(events.ChatAction())
async def message_handler(event):
   print(event)
```

Comment: Please put your code

Comment: Added. But I don't think it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telegram doesn't send the `user_left` update when the group has more than 50 members.

Comment: hmm, but it is possible to catch this with bot